# window.stripe is not a function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

I am trying to create a stripe checkout project but was stuck when I found that the loadStripe promise was not working fine and I have to change the code window.stripe but this is also not working .

Her is my react code :

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { isAuth } from "../helpers/auth";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import styles from "./Pricing.module.scss";
import ScriptTag from "react-script-tag";
const Stripe = require('stripe')
const stripe = window.Stripe('pk_xxxxxx373428')
export const Pricing = () => {
  const buttonValue = useRef();

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const setBtnValue = (e) => {
    buttonValue.current = e.target.value;
  };
  const checkoutHandler = async (e) => {
    const btnValue = buttonValue.current;
    console.log(btnValue);
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/checkout", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        btnValue,
      }),
    })
      .then((result) => result.json())
      .then(({ sessionID }) => stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionID }))
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result.error.message);
      });
  };
return (
<div>
  <ScriptTag
    isHydrating={true}
    type="text/javascript"
    src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"
  />
<form onSubmit = {checkoutHandler}>
        <button
          value= 'price_bdsahfbadshb'
          type="submit"
          className="btn"
          name="product"
          onClick={setBtnValue}
        >
          Upgrade Now
        </button>
</div>
)
}
```

Here is my backend code :

```
router.post('/checkout' , async(req,res) => {
    const product = req.body;
    console.log(product);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you want to redirect, just try adding `<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>` into `index.html` (if not added) so you will able to use `window.Stripe`.

and remove line `const Stripe = require('stripe')`

if you want more clarification, go through its [official documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/js/including).

Comment: can you format the code , I don't want to use CheckoutForm element by stripe , I just want to redirect them to stripe portal

Comment: Hey bro , I am getting an error : "Indicate whether to send a cookie in a cross-site request by specifying its SameSite attribute" . Here is my the code of server.js in which I have even set headers for cookies  
app.use((req,res) => {
    res.cookie('cookie', 'value', { sameSite: 'none', secure: true })
})

Comment: If you just want to redirect to the Stripe Portal. You can create a Checkout Session on your server side then have your server return a 303 redirect to the Session's URL. Server redirects are simpler and less prone to breaking than `redirectToCheckout` https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object#checkout_session_object-url

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a framework such as vue, react, angular

copy the below script to index.html

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3"></script>
```